# How to let PIL's Image.open find files from static?

Tags: django, python-imaging-library

I want to access a file in static from a module called "generate.py" inside my app. However I don't really have any idea how to do it.
I believe I've properly "installed" the app because i can access the .html file in the App

Things I've tried in generate.py

```
1 - 
from django.conf.urls.static import static

Image.Open(static('resources/App/template/photothatiwanttoopen.jpg'))
```

Error I get from code above: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

```
2 - 
from django.conf import settings

Image.Open(settings.STATIC_URL+'resources/App/template/photothatiwanttoopen.jpg')
```

Error I get from code above: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/resources/App/template/photothatiwanttoopen.jpg'

Here's my folder structure view

```
- Project
  - App
    - templates
      - App
        - app.html
    - apps.py
    - generate.py <<< Script
    - models.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
  - Project
    - settings.py and stuffs
  - static
    - resources
      - App
        - template
          - photothatiwanttoopen.jpg
  - manage.py and stuffs
```

Here's last few lines of my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STATIC_URL has no concept of the actual location on the filesystem.

That's where STATIC_ROOT comes into play.

Your optimal choice is likely going to be:

Image.Open(os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'resources/App/template/photothatiwanttoopen.jpg'))

That is assuming of course you've already collected the staticfiles (manage.py collectstatic) and you have imported STATIC_ROOT from django settings.